# Place holder not working in application.yml

Tags: spring-boot

trying to set instance homePageUrl url with `http://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/` for zuul to forward requests but getting exception:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "${server.port}"

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
management:
    context-path: 
    port : ${MANAGEPORT:9000}
    ssl : 
        enabled : false

server:
    port : ${PORT:8080}

endpoints:
    enabled: "true"
    health:
        enabled: "true"
        sensitive: "false"
    info:
        enabled: "true"
        sensitive: "false"
    metrics:
        enabled: "true"
    logfile:
        enabled: "true"
    restart:
        enabled: true
#Eureka Client configuration
eureka:
    client:
        healthcheck: 
        enabled: "true"
        sensitive: "true"
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        useDnsForFetchingServiceUrls: false
        serviceUrl: 
            defaultZone: "http://${DISCOVERYAPP:localhost}:${DISCOVERYPORT:8761}/eureka/"
    instance:
        preferIpAddress: true
        statusPageUrl: http://${eureka.hostname}:9000/info
        healthCheckUrl: http://${eureka.hostname}:9000/health
        homePageUrl: "http://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/"
        instanceId: "${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}"
        metadataMap:
            tenant: "${tenant:default}"
            management : 
                port : ${management.port}
                context-path : ${management.context-path}
```

Here is the exception:

java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "${server.port}"

here is the pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.5.18.RELEASE
         
    
    com.xxx.enterprise
    authserver
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    authserver
    Auth server

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>

    </dependency> 
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: remove "" double quotes

Comment: Tried but not working . same issue.

Comment: Ok you can remove / slash ..

Comment: No same exceptions

Comment: I'm not be able to reproduce this issue, can you share your code on some repo?